# How to disable "Screen is pinned" message from kisok mode app android development

Tags: android, toast, kiosk-mode

Hello all I want to disable the message "screen is pinned This keeps it in view until you unpinned...". This bubble/Toast is always showing me in my app I am developing a kiosk mode app

[image: Picture for the Toast/Bubble]

Any kind of help will be really grateful for me as I am a beginner in android development

Comment: Is there no answer to this one yet?

Comment: Did you got any solution?